# Как отфильтровть список таймзон по стране

Tags: java, kotlin, locale, timezone

Ищу способ отфильтровать список таймзон по стране в java/kotlin. В распоряжении есть utc offset в минутах

Стандартный метод `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(utcOffset)` возвращает список `id` таймзон, которые бьются по частям света, список для оффсета включает все части света, лежащие на этой долготе.  Русские города находятся на одном уровне с другими, и попадают в `Europe`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из таймзоны можно получать `display name`

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone(id).getDisplayName(Locale.getDefault())
```

Я хочу использовать приоритетно `id` российских городов. И только если таких в списке доступных для данного оффсета нет, то только тогда брать `first` из списка. Есть ли возможность как то отфильтровать эти `id` по стране? Может в java есть какая-нибудь статическая утилита, которая хранит названия городов для страны? Или есть ещё какой то способ?

Понимаю, что города можно достать из API, например Open Street Map, но в данном случае это оверхед. Если понадобится использую этот способ, а пока ищу возможность сделать такое стандартными средствами.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/TimeZone#getAvailableIDs(java.lang.String))

country     String: a two-letter ISO 3166 country code, or null to return zones not associated with any country